# selenium find element by id with firefox failed

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver, getelementbyid

I'm using Windows MobaXTerm for execute command. i execute Selenium by this command :

```
cd /drives/c/selenium; java -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://proxy.wideip -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128  -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\selenium\geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -port 4444
```

My geckodriver is into version 0.20 (the last actualy) My selenium version is greater then 3 and in fact include marionette.

For try to identify my problem i'm using postman.
Step 1 : Create session
Step 2 : set Url
Step 3 : get element by id

In step get element by id i have this result (in chrome)

```
{
    "sessionId": "448e264843b4bbf506f03491b2bf940d",
    "status": 0,
    "value": {
        "ELEMENT": "0.28994850647447534-1"
    }
}
```

and this result in firefox :

```
{
    "state": "success",
    "sessionId": null,
    "hCode": 23764448,
    "value": {
        "element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf": "17752648-8258-4338-8a0e-40be95c874c4"
    },
    "class": "org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response",
    "status": 0
}
```

For query i'm using same :

```
http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/{{selenium_session_id}}/element
```

and for query body i'm sending same :

```
{"using":"id","value":"id_button_submit"}
```

Of course i'm using same url / and same try.
But in FF i'm don't have result.value.ELEMENT, and if i don't have it, i can't have driverElementId, and click into, all my try's scenario is failed for FF

I'm using last Developer FF version.

May you give me idea for identify my problem and solve it please ?

Comment: I have send session into FF try ("sessionId": null, is only the result)

Comment: How is find element by id failing with Firefox ? From your post both Firefox and Chrome return an element. With Chrome the element is in `value['ELEMENT']` and with Firefox, the element is `value['element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf']`.

Comment: When i json_decode, how may i know the properties will use "-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf" suffix to the element ?So behat, who plays my scenario is lost.

Comment: Those id are generated randomly by the driver to keep track of the DOM elements. If you don't know the driver, you should then check for both keys: `ELEMENT` and `element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf`.

Comment: 2 problems to this solution, behat use only `ELEMENT`, of course i can fork it for update but very long, second problem, `element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf` is not fix, that make the getter of id more harder to create 

Are there really no solutions already planned to recapture an element by are id under FF? (It seems to me a basic case, that I can not do even using the docker of selenium for FF)

Comment: Don't expect to get it working with the same requests. The protocol between Chrome and Firefox is a bit different. Firefox has moved to the [Selenium 3 protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) while Chrome still rely on the [Selenium 2 protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol).